# Conditional Rename of Multiple Files - Powershell

Tags: powershell, rename

**Scenario**: Folder with more than one file(There are a maximum of 5 files). Each file starts with a character(does not repeat) followed by numbers. e.g: A123,B234,C123...

**Objective**: Rename the files according to a predetermined mapping. e.g: if A=1, B=2 etc. Then the File Starting with "A" becomes "1.", the file starting with "B" becomes "2." and so on. e.g: A123 => 1.A123

**My Solution**: I am not fluent in PowerShell but here is my attempt in achieving the above objective.

```
powershell "cd C:\Temp ; dir | ForEach-Object{if ($_.Name -Like "A*") {Rename-Item $_ "1.$_"} else {if ($_.Name -like "B*") {Rename-Item $_ "2.$_"} else{if($_.Name -like "C*"){Rename-Item $_ "3.$_"}}}}"
```

I needed the script to be executed from cmd and also in a specific folder (hence the cd and then the composed rename command).

This gets the job done but I would really appreciate if anyone could simplify things and show me a more prettier way at dealing with the situation.

Comment: So, number files starting at 1, and progressing sequentially? Or number files based on the first character of the file? So you have a folder with A123, B456, and F789. Do they become 1.A123, 2.B456, and 3.F789? Or do they become 1.A123, 2.B456, and 5.F789?

Comment: The file name based on first character. Just like 1.A123, 2.B456, and 5.F789 from your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can convert a letter to a number using something like:

```
[int][char]"F"
```

That will output 70. So, for your need you just need to get the first character of the file name, which is a simple `SubString(0,1)` call, then run it through `ToUpper()` to make sure you don't get any lower case letters, and then do the `[int][char]` bit to it, and subtract 64.

```
powershell "cd C:\Temp ; dir | ForEach-Object{$NewNameNum = [int][char]$_.Name.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() - 64;Rename-Item $_ "$NewNameNum.$_"}
```

**Edit:** Ok, so your original question is misleading, and should be edited to more accurately represent your request. If you are not assigning A=1, B=2, C=3 as a direct translation I can see 2 good options. First is a hashtable lookup.

```
PowerShell "$NmbrConv = @{'A'=3;'B'=1;'C'=9;'D'=2};dir c:\temp\*|%{$NewNameNum = $NmbrConv[$_.Name.Substring(0,1)];Rename-Item $_ "$NewNameNum.$_"}
```

This defines what letters convert to what numbers, then for each file just references the hashtable to get the number.

The other option is the `Switch` command. Running it in-line gets kind of ugly, but here's what it would look like formatted nicely.

```
Switch(GCI C:\Temp){
    "^a" {$NewNameNum=3}
    "^b" {$NewNameNum=1}
    "^c" {$NewNameNum=9}
    "^d" {$NewNameNum=2}
    default {Rename-Item $_ "$NewNameNum.$_"}
}
```

Then if you need it all in one line you remove new lines and replace them with semicolons.

```
powershell 'Switch(GCI C:\Temp){"^a" {$NewNameNum=3};"^b" {$NewNameNum=1};"^c" {$NewNameNum=9};"^d" {$NewNameNum=2};default {Rename-Item $_ "$NewNameNum.$_"}}'
```

Comment: Thank you very much @TheMadTechnician. But can you please help me in writing the if else construct in a better way. The reason being that i have a random relation instead of the given simple relation. i.e. I need to replace A=>3,B=>1,C=>9,D=2 etc and not 1,2,3,4 respectively.

Comment: Then you're better off creating a hashtable to reference, or using the `Switch` command.